# meteor update method not working

Tags: meteor, meteor-collections

this is my colletion:

```
{
    "_id" : "Kan6btPXwNiF84j8e",
    "title" : "Chapter Title 1",
    "businessId" : "qmWJ3HtZrpka8dpbM",
    "createdBy" : "GfdPfoPTiSwLv8TBR",
    "sections" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "T5KAfTcCb7pCudT3a",
            "type" : "TEXT",
            "data" : {
                "text" : "<h1>2</h1><h1>asd</h1>"
            },
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-12-03T10:35:59.023Z"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-12-03T10:35:59.023Z")
        }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-12-02T12:15:16.577Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-12-03T12:54:50.591Z")
}
```

this is the meteor method I am calling from client side

```
deleteSection: function (section_id, chapter_id) {


        chaptersCollection.update(
            {$and: [{_id: chapter_id}, {'sections.id': section_id}]},
            {$pull: {'sections': {'id': section_id}}},
            function (err, numAffected) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return err;
                }else{
                    console.log(numAffected);
                }
            });
        return 'Section Successfully Deleted';
    }
```

in callback function of meteor method, it returns 1 as affected rows. But on server document is not updating.

Any suggestion where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need $and?

```
deleteSection: function (section_id, chapter_id) {
    chaptersCollection.update(
        {_id: chapter_id, 'sections.id': section_id},
        {$pull: {'sections': {'id': section_id}}},
        function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return err;
            }else{
                console.log('success');
                return 'success';
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: it doesn't matter, I tried not working @HafizAllyLalani

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I tried to use pull in a project. So instead of using $pull, I handled the array outside of the database and then set the array as the one I handled outside. So maybe you can try something like that as an alternative way

```
deleteSection: function (section_id, chapter_id){

     const oldArray = chaptersCollection.findOne(chapter_id).sections;
     const newArray = oldArray.filter(function(section) {
                         return section.id !== section_id
                         });

     chaptersCollection.update({_id: chapter_id},
                               {$set: {sections: newArray}},
                               function (err, numAffected) {
                                   if (err) {
                                       console.log(err);
                                       return err;
                                    }else{
                                       console.log(numAffected);
                                    }
                                });
     return 'Section Successfully Deleted';

}
```

Comment: this is an alternative method to achieve what i want, does not resolve the issue. Thank You for answer. @CagriYardimci